# Removing Complications from my Watch app

Tags: xcode, watchos-2, apple-watch-complication

I had some really good ideas for a complication, but realized that the data in my app changes too often, and have decided that a complication wouldn't be a good fit.

I had previously selected the Complications check box when I created my app.

How would I now remove complications from my Watch App?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should make the following changes to remove the complication from your Xcode project:

**Within the WatchKit Extension group folder:**

- Select `Assets.xcassets`, then delete `Complication.complicationset`.
- Select `Info.plist`, then remove the following keys:

  ```
  CLKComplicationPrincipalClass
  CLKComplicationSupportedFamilies
  ```
- Right-click `ComplicationController.swift` file, then select Delete -> Move to trash.

**Within the project's Build Settings:**

- Look for **Asset Catalog Compiler - Options, Watch Complication Name**, then delete the "Complication" value so that setting is blank.

  *You can quickly find that build setting by searching for* Complication.

The complication has now been removed from your project's watch app (extension).

**Optional step to clean build folder:**

You can select the Product menu, hold down the option key, then select Clean Build Folder. This will remove any intermediate files that were in the previous build which were related to your complication.